# Why does the animation in a library object not play when it's a "Graphics" item?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Is there any way I can determine why an animation in a "Graphics" library object of 10 frames length does not play if the main time line has only 1 frame? 
When the same item is changed to "MovieClip", it plays fine, regardless of the number of frames!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MovieClips have their own timelines that will play regardless of what their parent timeline does. Graphics objects are locked to their parent timeline.

The biggest upside of this is that you can preview any animation in them by scrubbing the parent timeline, as opposed to MovieClips where only the first frame will show.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand "MovieClips have their own timelines....Graphics objects are locked to their parent timeline." 

When I create a graphics it has it's own time line. I can see them by double clicking . So what does it men "Locked to parent time line".

Comment: It means that a MovieClip will progress through its frames regardless of what its parent is doing. A Graphic will be at frame one when its parent is at frame one, frame two when its parent is at frame two and so on. This is why your MovieClip plays when your main timeline only has one frame. Should you extend your main timeline to be ten frames your Graphic clip would play too.